# Arrays Java beginner

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble storing values into my `monthlySales` array. Also, how can I retrieve the values to use in other methods such as `totalSales`? Plus, I have errors in `getSales()` method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class SalesTracking 
{
    static DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat ("$#,##0.00");
    static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); //create a scanner object that reads from the keyboard (System.in)
    private static final double[] monthlySales = new double[12]; //create monthlysales array
    private static final String[] monthArray = {"January" , "February" , "March" , "April", "May",
              "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
              "November", "December"}; //create 12-month array
    static void getSales(){
        int size = monthArray.length; 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        System.out.print("Please Enter Sales for " + monthArray[i] + ":");
        monthlySales[i] = input.nextDouble();
        } //get sales method to store values into monthlysales
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        getSales();
        totalSales();
        computeHighestMonth(monthlySales);
        computeLowestMonth(monthlySales);
```

Comment: `getSales()` is a method inside the `main()` method. You can't do that!

Comment: `getSales` is declared within another method, you can't do this Java, you need to move so it's out side of the method

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: I updated my new code with the fixes plus add my new methods but I'm having a issue with getting the lowest value.

Comment: It's better to post a new question rather than overhaul the old one. Otherwise, people don't understand what the posted answers refer to.

Comment: Ok I'll do that thank you

Comment: Please revert this question to what you had before and move the current information to a new question. Also, you don't have the code for computeLowestMonth(). Finally, there's no need to pass a static class variable as a parameter, because all class methods have access to the variable.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry I am new to this still not sure what the rules are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, let's break down your multiple sub-questions.

> Having trouble storing values into my monthlySales array.

First of all, avoid C syntax and write your declaration as:

`private static final double[] monthlySales = new double[12];`

This emphasizes that `monthlySales` is of the *type* `double[]`. Now, for your question. The below line is what's giving you trouble.

`monthlySales = input.nextDouble();`

When you declared `monthlySales` as `final`, that actually means that you can't have the reference variable point to anything else. Here, you're attempting to make the variable point to a `double`, which can't happen both because the variable must point to a `double[]` and the `final` declaration.

You want this instead, where changing the values in the array is perfectly fine (Java's `final` keyword is a little weird):

`monthlySales[i] = input.nextDouble();`

> Plus I have errors on public static void getSales() method.

This is because you've defined the `getSales` method *inside of* `main()`. In Java, you can't define methods inside of other methods (you can do this with classes, however).

I believe you want to strip out the `getSales` definition entirely, since your main client appears to be reading from standard input. If you need to access your arrays from another class, define getter methods outside of `main`.

> Also how can I retrieve the values to use in other methods such as totalSales?

Because you've assigned the values to the static members `monthlySales` and `monthArray`, you can already access those variables from your other static methods.

Note that since you have no non-static variables or methods, you can't create multiple instances of `SalesTracking` meaningfully, since all instances will share the same set of data.

> Errors on void(invalid type) and getSales (Illegal modifier for parameter getSales; only final is permitted)

These stem from your `getSales` definition inside of `main`. If you define the method outside or remove it entirely, you'll be fine.

**EDIT:** Fix your `getSales()` like so:

```
public static void getSales() {
    try (
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // try-with-resources
    ) {
        int size = monthArray.length; 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            System.out.print("Please Enter Sales for " + monthArray[i] + ":");
            monthlySales[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    getSales();
}
```

Comment: Great! I appreciate your complete breakdown it helped alot. I fixed the following errors but do I need to add the scanner within getSales() method because I am getting this error  *input cannot be resolved*

Comment: If you want to make a getSales() method and call it from main(), that's fine. In that case, your Scanner object needs to be created in getSales(). I'll edit my post to reflect that. The input cannot be resolved error comes from not having a valid Scanner instance.

Comment: Got it!!! I updated the new code with the fixes you recommended but there's a new problem with my computeLowest method. It only returns a $0.00 value

Answer (score 0):

Like it has been said in the comments move this method outside main. 
More over you will then need to create an instance of this class in main and pass `input` either via constructor or as a parameter to this class.

Here is the modified version of your code (I have not tested it but should work)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SalesTracking 
{
    private static final double monthlySales[] = new double[12];
    private static final String[] monthArray = {"January" , "February" , "March" , "April", "May",
              "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
              "November", "December"};
    static void totalSales(){

    }
    static void averageSales(){

    }
    static void highestMonth(){

    }
    static void lowestMonth(){

    }

    public static void getSalesUsingStaticMethodWhichBelongsToClass(double input)
    {
        SalesTracking salesTracking = new SalesTracking();
        salesTracking.getSalesUsingNonStaticMethodWhichBelongsToInstanceAndRecommended(input);

    } 

    public void getSalesUsingNonStaticMethodWhichBelongsToInstanceAndRecommended(double input)
    {
        int size = monthArray.length; 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        System.out.print("Please Enter Sales for " + monthArray[i] + ":");
        monthlySales[i] = input;
        }

    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        //create a scanner object that reads from the keyboard (System.in)
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        getSalesUsingStaticMethodWhichBelongsToClass(input.nextDouble());

        //OR Using Instance which you should be using . No need to make class method static for no reason
        SalesTracking salesTracking = new SalesTracking();
        salesTracking.getSalesUsingNonStaticMethodWhichBelongsToInstanceAndRecommended(input.nextDouble());


    }//end main

}//end class
```

---

Long method names like this are not needed in main classes but are okay and recommended for unit tests . I have just used them to show exaplain the point

Comment: Thank you for your comments our professor wants all methods to be static . All methods should be STATIC therefore no object will need to be instantiated to call them.  All methods must be called from the main method. Sales amounts should be rounded to two decimal places. .

Answer (score 0):

*:Please use the Java Jdk 1.8

entity:

```
class Sales {

public Month getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(Month month) {
    this.month = month;
}

private Month month;

public double getSales() {
    return sales;
}

public void setSales(double sales) {
    this.sales = sales;
}

private double sales;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "month->" + getMonth() + ",sales->" + getSales();
}}
```

Calculate:

```
/**
  * @author puruidong
  * @version 2015-07-10
  */
public class Main {
private static final double monthlySales[] = new double[12];
private static final String[] monthArray = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
        "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
        "November", "December"};


private Set<Sales> salesList = new HashSet<Sales>(12);


public void totalSales() {

    double count = salesList.stream().mapToDouble(new ToDoubleFunction<Sales>() {
        @Override
        public double applyAsDouble(Sales value) {
            return value.getSales();
        }
    }).sum();
    System.out.println("total->" + count);
}

static void averageSales() {

}

static void highestMonth() {

}

static void lowestMonth() {

}

public void showSales() {
    salesList.forEach((x) -> {
        System.out.println(x.toString());
    });


}

public void getSalesUsingNonStaticMethodWhichBelongsToInstanceAndRecommended(Scanner sc) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 11) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)");
        int months = sc.nextInt();
        Sales sales = new Sales();
        switch (Month.of(months)) {
            case JANUARY:
                sales.setMonth(Month.JANUARY);
                break;
            case FEBRUARY:
                sales.setMonth(Month.FEBRUARY);
                break;
            case MARCH:
                sales.setMonth(Month.MARCH);
                break;
            case APRIL:
                sales.setMonth(Month.APRIL);
                break;
            case MAY:
                sales.setMonth(Month.MAY);
                break;
            case JUNE:
                sales.setMonth(Month.JUNE);
                break;
            case JULY:
                sales.setMonth(Month.JUNE);
                break;
            case AUGUST:
                sales.setMonth(Month.AUGUST);
                break;
            case SEPTEMBER:
                sales.setMonth(Month.SEPTEMBER);
                break;
            case OCTOBER:
                sales.setMonth(Month.OCTOBER);
                break;
            case NOVEMBER:
                sales.setMonth(Month.NOVEMBER);
                break;
            case DECEMBER:
                sales.setMonth(Month.DECEMBER);
                break;
            default:
                System.err.println("--input error--");
                break;
        }
        if (sales.getMonth() != null) {
            sc.reset();
            System.out.println("Please enter turnover:");
            double turnover = sc.nextDouble();
            sales.setSales(turnover);
            salesList.add(sales);
        }
        i++;
    }
    showSales();
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    totalSales();


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Main salesTracking = new Main();
    salesTracking.getSalesUsingNonStaticMethodWhichBelongsToInstanceAndRecommended(input);
}//end main

}//end class
```

The result:

```
Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)
1
Please enter turnover:
1
Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)
2
Please enter turnover:
2
Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)
3
Please enter turnover:
3
Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)
4
Please enter turnover:
4
Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)
5
Please enter turnover:
5
Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)
6
Please enter turnover:
6
Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)
7
Please enter turnover:
7
Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)
8
Please enter turnover:
8
Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)
9
Please enter turnover:
9
Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)
10
Please enter turnover:
10
Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)
11
Please enter turnover:
11
Please enter a month to be recorded?(1-12)
12
Please enter turnover:
12
------------------------------
month->DECEMBER,sales->12.0
month->JANUARY,sales->1.0
month->APRIL,sales->4.0
month->AUGUST,sales->8.0
month->MAY,sales->5.0
month->MARCH,sales->3.0
month->JUNE,sales->7.0
month->OCTOBER,sales->10.0
month->NOVEMBER,sales->11.0
month->FEBRUARY,sales->2.0
month->JUNE,sales->6.0
month->SEPTEMBER,sales->9.0
----------------------------
total->78.0
```